# Postgres Trigger - Working with 2 different tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have 2 tables:

```
Books - isbn (PK), title, qty-in-stock
Orderlist - ordernum (PK), isbn, quantity
```

My goal is to insert a record into orderlist and then, if matching isbns, add the quantity to qty-in-stock

My function and trigger is not correct -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION books_upd() RETURNS trigger as $bookupd$
BEGIN 
--IF   THE ISBN MATCHES BETWEEN BOOKS AND ORDERLIST
-- ADD THE EXISTING QTY_IN_STOCK (BOOKS)  TO QUANTITY (ORDERLIST)
QTY_IN_STOCK:=QTY_IN_STOCK+QUANTITY;
--END IF
RETURN NEW;
$bookupd$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER books_upd
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on orderlist
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE books_upd();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger function is quite complicated because of different cases of insert and update.

When a user updates the order, then the function should:

- add to `qty_in_stock` the difference between new and old `quantities`    if `isbns` are the same or
- subtract old `quantity` from `qty_in_stock` of one book and add new `quantity` to `qty_in_stock` of another book when `isbns` are       different.

Additionally, the function should reject changes if the given `isbn` does not exist in `books`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION books_upd() 
RETURNS trigger as $bookupd$
DECLARE
    v_quantity int;
BEGIN
    v_quantity = NEW.quantity;
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF OLD.isbn != NEW.isbn THEN
            UPDATE books
            SET qty_in_stock = qty_in_stock- OLD.quantity
            WHERE isbn = OLD.isbn;
        ELSE
            v_quantity = NEW.quantity- OLD.quantity;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    UPDATE books
    SET qty_in_stock = qty_in_stock+ v_quantity
    WHERE isbn = NEW.isbn;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Uknown isbn';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$bookupd$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Read more about [NEW, OLD and TG_OP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

---

The trigger function only for insert is really simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION books_upd() 
RETURNS trigger as $bookupd$
BEGIN
    UPDATE books
    SET qty_in_stock = qty_in_stock+ NEW.quantity
    WHERE isbn = NEW.isbn;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$bookupd$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Actually, I made this too complicated.  Sorry!

We would only have an insert case.
Also, isbn from orderlist is foreign key to isbn in books.  So, it will always be found.

I don't believe we need your second bullet point. 

Your answer was very helpful!  Given these simplifiers, what is a new coding?

Comment: An additional challenge as business rules are developed-

I found out that 
   SET qty_in_stock = qty_in_stock+ NEW.quantity